# !important tag not overriding CSS styles

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4, css-selectors, materialize

I am using Materialize.CSS framework and i am overriding most styles i want to change with !important tag in my stylesheet which is working as expected, but some element styles are not being overridden by my `!important` tag

I inspected dev tools and saw that the default style framework is applying on some elements like card card-title etc. already have !important tag applied over it which maybe is overriding my `important` or have a higher priority.

So please tell how to get around that.

[screenshot] [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/wVHgr.png

Comment: You probably need to inspect the [specificity](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Specificity#:~:text=Specificity%20is%20a%20weight%20that,type%20in%20the%20matching%20selector.&text=As%20per%20CSS%20rules%2C%20directly,element%20inherits%20from%20its%20ancestor.)

Comment: Can you create a sample jsfiddle of your issue, and share it here ?

It will be easier to help, and understand the exact issue.

Comment: The selector from Materialize is more specific than yours so it wil be used. Change yours to `.grey-text.text-darken-4` to override it. Or better yet remove the `text-darken-4` and `grey-text` class from the element

Comment: and this is exactly why you shouldn't liberally use `!important`

Answer (score 1):

both `.grey-text.text-darken-2` and `.grey-text` have `!important` but `.grey-text.text-darken-2`specificity is more than `.grey-text`. [more about that](https://css-tricks.com/specifics-on-css-specificity/).

Answer (score 1):

There are two ways you can go about this:

1. Add `!important` to the same CSS selector in a later point in the file.
2. Add another CSS selector of higher specificity, and apply `!important` to it.

Suggestion: It is always suggested to add a small code snippet which explains your problem. :D

Answer (score 1):

If your `!important` is overriden by another with higher priority you can always give priority to yours snipping a higher parent like `body`

For example. if:

```
.container .label {color:red !important;}
```

is overriden the same line you wrote, add this insteed:

```
body .container .label {color:red !important;}
```

Also, if you call an element in your css class with an `id` (#) it will override the same property called by a `class` even if it's placed before in the sheet order